# Two definitions of determinants

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I'm taking my second linear algebra course this semester. Since our semester just started, we are restudying some of the key results and definitions of the first linear algebra course. Each course presented a different definition of determinants:

**Definition 1:** Let $A\in M_n(\mathbb{F})$. $\det A$ is defined as an expansion of the first arrow $a_1'$: $$\det A:=\sum_{j=1}^{n}(-1)^{1+j}a_{1j}M_{1j}$$. It can also be defined as an expansion of any other arrow $a_i'$: $$\det A:=\sum_{j=1}^{n}(-1)^{i+j}a_{ij}M_{ij},$$ as well as an expansion of any column $a_j$: $$\det A:=\sum_{i=1}^{n}(-1)^{i+j}a_{ij}M_{ij}$$

**Definition 2:** A determinant of $M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{F})$ is an alternating n-linear function $\delta :M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{F})\to\mathbb{F}$, such that $\delta (I_n)=1$

My question is: Is there a way to derive one definition from the other? Whether it's from Definition 1 to Definition 2, or from 2 to 1. Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is somewhat lengthy and could be difficult for a beginner to do independently. It is done in detail in Section 1.4 of Artin's *Algebra*. The best approach is probably to prove that there is a unique determinant function satisfying Definition 2, and then prove that row and column expansion are valid for this definition.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to show is that for any square matrix $A=[a_{ij}]_n$, the value of $\sum_{j=1}(-1)^{i+j}a_{ij}M_{ij}$ is the same for any $i=1,2,3,...,n$.

Should be good enough a hint.